# Check if stored procedure is still running in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I tried using this code but still the Stored Procedure I've called is still running in the Database but in the code it is already finished.

```
$this->db->trans_start();

$this->db->query('CALL sp_process();'); 

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {# Something went wrong.

    $this->response->message[] = array(
            'message' => "Encountered a problem",
            'type' => 'error'
        );
} 
else {
    $this->db->trans_commit();
    $this->response->message[] = array(
        'message' => 'successfully processed',
        'type' => 'success'
    );
}
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Comment: $this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
        $this->db->trans_commit();
}

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of [Running Transactions Manually](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#running-transactions-manually):

> Make sure to use `$this->db->trans_begin()` when running manual
>   transactions, NOT `$this->db->trans_start()`.

So try by replacing your first line with `$this->db->trans_begin();`

Comment: Hi, I tried doing this but still the code is not sync with the database. The stored procedure is still running in the processlist.

Comment: @Sheng can you try by moving the call `$this->db->trans_complete();` after `$this->db->query('CALL sp_process();');` and before the status check?

Comment: @Sheng you're welcome :) I'm sorry it doesn't solve the issue. If it's not a problem can you also add an example of the stored procedure's definition?